# how to get chapter title in a rectangular frame

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

how to get chapter heading like this in pdflatex

[image]

can titlesec be used?

```
% hanging chapters
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang] 
{\normalfont \Large \bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{1em}{}
```

Comment: Which documentclass do you use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First tried using `titlesec`. Failed to coax it to work in the manner you wanted. Then redefined the definition from basics.

---

**The Solution**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{calc}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}

  \setlength{\fboxsep}{1.0mm}
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{1.0mm}\noindent\fbox{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{2.0mm}%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5mm}%
    \framebox[\textwidth-15.0pt][c]{\hspace*{0.25\parindent}\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\@chapapp--\thechapter\hfill#1}\hspace*{0.25\parindent}}}
    \par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\chapter{My Story of Boxed Chapters}

\end{document}
```

---

**Tweaking Tips**

Should you need to tweak the attributes, here are the tips.

1. To change the box width, tweak `\textwidth` in  `\framebox[\textwidth]`. 
   Right now I am assuming that you want the box to be exactly text width. Should you need it wider, you will want to use, something like `\framebox[1.2\textwidth]`.
2. The two `\fboxsep` and `\fboxrule` [control the separation from content and
   thickness of rule of the boxes](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes#framebox). Please set these to the values to your taste.
3. I have arbitrarily set the spaces before the word CHAPTER and after chapter name to `0.25\parindent`. Change these should you need otherwise.

---

**The Output**

Here is the output.

[image]

[image]

---

**Caution**

As you already know, you will not use long chapter names.

Comment: About `\hfuzz`: The problem is that `\framebox` creates a box of the given width *and then* adds the frame and the separation. Plus there is a paragraph indentation. So: precede the `\fbox` with `\noindent` and then use `\framebox[\textwidth-4.5cm]` (`calc` package required). Without these modification, the title sticks out into the right margin and is not aligned with the left margin.

Comment: @Dan Thanks. Previously tried to use `\noident`, without avail. Did not know about this strange behavior of `\framebox`. Anyway, updated the code.

Answer (score 5):

Here a suggestion using a frame drawing package:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[tikz]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{chapter}{outerlinewidth=3pt,middlelinewidth=1.5pt,innerlinewidth=1pt,%
outerlinecolor=blue!70!black,middlelinecolor=white,innerlinecolor=blue!50!black}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@@makechapterhead}[1]{%
 \chapterheadstartvskip
  {%
    \setlength{\parindent}{\z@}\setlength{\parfillskip}{\fill}%
    \normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@chapter{}%
    \begin{mdframed}[nobreak,style=chapter]
           \chapterformat\hfill\size@chapter{#1}
     \end{mdframed}\par%
  }%
  \nobreak\chapterheadendvskip
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) allows you to define your own styles by providing a `.tss` "style file":

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{filecontents,lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{filecontents,lipsum}
\begin{filecontents*}{chapframe.tss}
% Styles
% ~~~~~~

% 1:global 2:label 3:sep 4:style 5:after 6:left 7:right 8:title
% \ttl@<shape> and \ttlh@<shape> take the following eight
% arguments:
% {format}{label}{sep}{before}{after}{left}{right}{title}
% where before and after refer to the format.
% With the option explicit, #4 contains the title and #8 is
% empty.
\gdef\ttlh@chapframe#1#2#3#4#5#6#7#8{%
  \noindent%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{3\fboxrule}% Thicker outer rule
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{.5\fboxsep}% Thinner gap
  \framebox[\linewidth]{%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{.5\fboxrule}% Thinner inner rule
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{2\fboxsep}% Thicker gap
    \framebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-\fboxrule-2\fboxsep]{%
      #1\strut#2\hfill#4{#8}%
    }%
  }%
  \par%
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{titlesec}% http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec

\titleformat{\chapter}[chapframe]
{\normalfont \Large \bfseries}{\chaptertitlename~--~\thechapter}{1em}{}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Above I've defined/written `chapframe.tss` that sets the chapter in a double-framed style.

You may have to adjust the style if you use the `explicit` package option.